# Node.js/Grunt - Can't run Grunt's watch - why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to use the autoprefixer css post-processor. I am following a tutorial and have installed npm. Using a npm, I then installed grunt and autoprefixer inside my project root using that `package.json` file: https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer/blob/master/package.json

Following the tutorial, I then created this `Gruntfile.js` inside my project root:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        autoprefixer: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'build/style.css': 'style.css'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            styles: {
                files: ['style.css'],
                tasks: ['autoprefixer']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

After that the tutorial advises to use Grunt Watch using

```
./node_modules/.bin/grunt watch
```

Which results in

```
-bash: ./node_modules/.bin/grunt: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to navigate to the grunt folder inside my project, then it says

```
-bash: node_modules/grunt: is a directory
```

I also have a `node_modules` folder directly in my local user folder, but addressing that folder grunt also just tells me that its a folder.

Pleaser help me, why is this not working? I am willing to really learn grunt, but I am not even able to get started using the getting started guide...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed the `grunt-cli`? (`npm install grunt-cli -g`) What happens when you run `grunt` in your project root? The command you should be running is simply `grunt watch`, in your project root.

Edit: Your project root must also have a package.json file in which you define your development dependencies; e.g.

```
{
    "name":"yourprojectname",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "devDependencies":{
        "grunt":"*",
        "grunt-contrib-watch":"*",
        "grunt-autoprefixer":"*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `grunt-cli` is installed. Running `grunt watch` from my projekt root results in `Warning: Task "watch" not found. Use --force to continue.`

Comment: Your Gruntfile config looks fine to me. Is `grunt-contrib-watch` in your *local* `node_modules` directory? If not, run `npm install` in your project root and then run `grunt watch` again.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to solve the problem. It was a combination of mixing global and local installed modules and having wrong stuff in the package.json

Answer (score 1):

if there is acutally a space in the executable name you need to put it in quotes

"./node_modules/.bin/grunt watch"

otherwise linux will run "./node_modules/.bin/grunt" with watch as a flag.

if that still doesn't work,

could be a few problems, either your ldconfig isn't updated, the files aren't set to executable, or the user you are trying to execute the command with doesn't have permission.

first try running "ldconfig" (just type and run it)
more info here
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-shared-library-management.html

chmod -x the files to make them executable.

any luck?